# SpecFlow Parameter Bindings Using Examples

Tags: c#, .net, specflow, gherkin

I have the following in my SpecFlow `.feature` file.

```
Scenario: Signout
    Given I am signed in with an <userAccountType> account
    When I sign out
    Then I should see the signin page
Examples:
    | userAccountType |
    | AAD             |
    | MSA             |
```

This is the code in my step definition:

```
[Given(@"I am signed in with an (.*) account")]
public async Task GivenIAmSignedInWithAnAccount(string userAccountType)
{
    // ...
}
```

When this runs, I get the string `<userAccountType>` passed into the parameter in my method, instead of `AAD` or `MSA`.

Comment: Templates are supported only in scenario outlines, not scenarios. Change `Scenario:` to `Scenario Outline:` (you may have to fix the indenting of `Examples` as well).

Comment: @JeroenMostert That is indeed the answer.